# Google authentication with cookies (without DB) in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth

I want to authenticate users using Google and persist authentication using cookies.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(UpdateClientsCommandHandler));
        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sqlOptions =>
                        {
                            sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                        });
                    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
                }
            );
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "YourCustomScheme";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie("YourCustomScheme")
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "client-id";
                options.ClientSecret = "client-secret";
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/AuthCallback/IndexAsync");
                options.SignInScheme = "YourCustomScheme";
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
}
```

The user is successfully redirected to Google Auth and I can see that cookie `.AspNetCore.YourCustomScheme` is created. But then the user is just redirected back to the Google login page.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Change options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme to YourCustomScheme

Comment: @Tratcher doesn't help :(

Comment: What does your controller look like? `[Authorize]`?

Comment: Yes, just `[Authorize]` on the controller. Controller has one simple action.

Comment: Does it work any better if you replace `DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` with `DefaultScheme = "YourCustomScheme"`? Also, do you have AddIdentity anywhere, that will overwrite these settings.

Comment: 1. If I use `options.DefaultScheme = "YourCustomScheme";` user is redirected to the login page (which doesn't exist as I want google to be my login page). 2. No, I don't have `AddIdentity`

Comment: You kept DefaultChallengeScheme right?

Comment: No, I removed it.

Comment: Combination of `options.DefaultScheme = "YourCustomScheme";` and `options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` doesn't work

Comment: Want to show the rest of Startup? something is missing.

Comment: Updated question text, added entire startup excluding services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my problem is caused by the fact that I put `UseAuthentication` after `UseMvc`

Comment: Do you still have a working example on this? I am attempting to do the same thing and when I hit the controller with `[Authorize]` it performs what appears to be a login, but then redirects the user to /signin-google every time.